# Is it okay to use "yesterday" when describing some sudden change in the past?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Is it okay to use "yesterday" when describing some sudden change in the past? For example:

> That potion was really good. It really worked miracles when every
>   citizen of this country was given a chance to take a sip. Within just
>   one night, it turned stupid people into non-stupid, smart ones into
>   the wise, and the wise into geniuses. All those who were novices and
>   newbies just **yesterday** now became the most prominent experts and
>   gurus in their particular field.

Or would "the day before" (or something else) would still be better in this case?

Comment: What makes you think that **yesterday** might not be appropriate?

Comment: @JavaLatte Because I've always thought that "yesterday" meant "one night prior to now", that is, "one night prior to the moment of speaking/narration"; however, in my passage it's years before the moment of narration.

Comment: Strictly speaking, yesterday means one **day** before, not one **night** before https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yesterday. In narrative such as this, I think it is reasonable to use **yesterday** to refer to a situation shortly before some date in the past- in this case, the day before taking the potion.

Comment: @JavaLatte - "Strictly speaking, yesterday means one day before, not one night before" - So, if it's 7:00 am right now and I want to refer to some even that happened 15 hours ago, I cannot say "yesterday at 4:00 pm" because it was only one night before, that is, not one day before now???

Comment: Of course you can say this. I don't know how you read it to mean the complete opposite of what JavaLatte said, but yes, any time before 12:00 AM the previous day can be called yesterday.

Comment: @TobyMak "I don't know how you read it to mean the complete opposite of what JavaLatte said" - Why is it complete opposite? JavaLatte said "yesterday means one day before, not one night before", but in my example it's one night before, not day before (the time between 4:00 pm and 7:00 am includes a night, not a day).

Comment: If it's 7:00 am, then 4:00 pm which was 15 hours ago is still yesterday. A day begins at 12 a.m, and ends at 11:59 p.m the next night. Since you pass 12 a.m on the way to 4:00 pm, then that time is yesterday. Perhaps you were confused about day (24 hours) and daytime (less than 24 hours)?

Comment: @TobyMak "Perhaps you were confused about day (24 hours) and daytime (less than 24 hours)?" - JavaLatte didn't say "yesterday means one daytime period before". Instead, he said "yesterday means one day before". In fact, in my very first answer to him I said, "I've always thought 'yesterday' meant 'one night prior to now'" and by 'one night' there I meant '24 hours', but he then replied and said, "One day before, not one night before."

Comment: I can't reason with you, but yesterday is completely appropriate in this context.

Comment: @TobyMak I don't want to reason either. I just want to understand the logic here and, thus, understand where my misunderstanding is. Can you, please, help me out here? Look, as I gather from your comments, by _one day_ you mean a period of 24 hours. Right? And you also agree that, as JavaLatte said, _yesterday_ means _one day ago_. Right? Then _yesterday_ should mean _24 hours ago_. Right? But in my example it's only 15 hours ago! Where is my misunderstanding here? What do I get wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94973/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-brilliant).

Comment: *Yesterday* means one **calendar day** previous. If today is the 10th, then yesterday was the 9th. If it's currently 1:00 a.m. on the 10th, then 11:00 p.m. on the 9th was yesterday. In the passage in the question, *yesterday* can be taken either literally or figuratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To use yesterday metaphorically, take this:**

All those who were novices and newbies **just yesterday** now became the most prominent experts and gurus in their particular field.

**and make it this:**

All those who just yesterday were novices and newbies now became the most prominent experts and gurus in their fields.

It is usually expressed with the "just yesterday" right after the "who".

Here is one example from a reliable publication:

How is it that both my daughters, **who just yesterday** were upstairs trying on their new school clothes, are this year dressing their own children ready for first grade?

[example of just yesterday](http://archive.boston.com/news/local/articles/2010/08/22/bittersweet_song_of_september/)

For a non-metaphorical use, it's best to use: the day before.

Comment: Great answer, I even briefly thought "this is the right answer" and to delete mine.  however - the original question is not intending to use yesterday metaphorically. "Within just one night" is "literal"

Comment: @Sam The paragraph shows that it is most definitely metaphorical for: not so long ago. If it had not been metaphorical, it should be: who the day before. The fact it says one night does not really change that.

Answer (score 1):

> Or would "the day before" (or something else) would still be better in this case?

Yes. "the day before" is more strictly accurate. "yesterday" does mean "one day prior to now".

However, "yesterday" is probably still acceptable, because

1. in context, it makes sense to the reader.
2. can be explained by the historical present (also called the historic present, dramatic present, and narrative present). With this tense, even though the story is set in the past, you may use the present tense to recount it.

IMHO, when reading the passage and encountering "yesterday" I thought "that sounds slightly wrong" and also "you can probably get away with it".